# WITH RECOMPILE в процедурах MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

На сколько я знаю, то при создании процедуры к ней крепится на мертво план-выполнения, до тех пор пока сервер не перезагрузится, либо процедура пересоздастся, либо не будет запущена с опцией `WITH RECOMPILE`, что может повлечь за собой просадку производительности из-за устаревшего плана.

Предположим, процедура вызывает вложенные процедуры.

1. Если процедура, которая вызывается с `WITH RECOMPILE` вызывает внутри
   себя процедуры без `WITH RECOMPILE`, то будет ли рассчитан оптимальный
   план вызова внутренних процедур?
2. И наоборот: Что будет если внешняя процедура не имеет `WITH RECOMPILE`, а внутренние имеют.

Comment: _"крепится намертво план-выполнения"_ нет, намертво не крепится, в процедурах могут происходить statement level рекомпиляции, если query processor сочтёт, что recompilation threshold превышен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. План будет пересчитан только для родительской хранимой процедуры.
2. Тут обратная история, планы будут пересчитаны только для для дочерних.

Для проверки можете использовать:

```
select o.name, s.*
from master..syscacheobjects s
inner join sysobjects o
on s.objid = o.id
where s.dbid = DB_ID()
order by o.name
```

Comment: Т.е получается, что при вызове процедуры SQL Server, образно говоря, опрашивает вложенные процедуры , а те в свою очередь возвращают свои планы из этих заплаток строит весь план вызова процедуры с подпроцедурами?

Comment: Образно говоря да, но если вы посмотрите план своей родительской процедуры то увидите только ее план, без планов дочерних хранимых процедур.